# Connecting to database via constructor, close via destructor?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question regarding database connection in PHP and MySQL. I wonder if it is possible to keep the database connection open, opening using a class and defining the connection in the constructor, then closing the connection again in the destructor.

I currently have a class which is an "html"-class, I have my website using this for it's layout and such. Would it pose any sort of (later on) problems, security risks or such if I would do as I earlier propose?

Regards,

Comment: There is no need for the destructor closing. The MySQL connection will be closed by default when PHP finishes execution. Unless you have a specific need for closing the connection prematurely (like connecting to multiple databases or the like) I would not worry about it, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not uncommon to open a connection inside a constructor, and often then to store the connection resource in a property of the class.

You can explicitly close the database connection in the constructor, however it isn't usually necessary to do so since PHP will close the connection implicitly when it is no longer needed by the script.

```
class db {
  public $connection;

  public function __construct($params...) {
     $this->connection = mysql_connect(...);
     if (!$this->connection) {
        // throw an exception or set an error status...
     }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, yes, but even then I'd recommend using a persistent connection. You might consider applying a Singleton pattern to such an object so that it's not as likely to be used incorrectly. Also consider making the member variable which holds the connection resource to be static.

As stated by Michael, when the script ends, the object will go away, but the advantage of using a destructor, if you wish, is to call it before the script ends for any special reasons.

And, depending on your actual use case, I might suggest separating your layout-related classes from your database-related classes.

Comment: Any specific reasons to separate them? My idea to do this was that my websites layout is predefined by my "htmlclass" __constructor. Thus, when I open any page on my website, with the design, the database connection would be there and all I'd have to do was to run my queries, without ever have to think about my connection.

Comment: It's called separation of concerns, or more generally, encapsulation. Your layout object is concerned with rendering page elements. Your database object would be concerned with database transactions. The solution would be to have your "htmlclass" __constructor create or use an instance of the database class internally. So they stay separate, but one uses the other.

Comment: Persistent connection to a MySql database?  Might want to rethink that bit of advice.  Especially if you use transactions or table locks.

Comment: @Cerad Valid: if his site has super-high loads or has a complex architecture such that he needs transactions and table locks, then persistent connections may not be the best-performing option. We aren't sure from the OP whether this is the situation or not.

Comment: @Matt - Kind of backwards.  With MySql there really is no advantage with using persistent connections and of course they have several potential major disadvantages.  I would suggest that it is probably up to you to justify using a persistent connection.  I would also suggest that even simple sites can benefit from transactions.  Always stayed away from table locking myself.  Guess it's off topic though.

Comment: You bring up points that have always been disputed (do a quick Google search). It is up to each his own.

Comment: That is true.  But I kind of side with the people that actually wrote php. [PHP Manual Persistent Connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php).  Be curious to hear your reasons though or maybe read a link or two.

Comment: Basically, Matt's answer suggested using a persistent connection and I was just wondering why.  You can read up about them in the link I posted.  By default connections are non-persistent so I really would not worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

not sure about that, but i know you can send a SQL connection inside a function param.